# Return a MySQLi query results from a function while using "Prepare Statment"

Tags: php, function, mysqli, null, prepared-statement

It's my first time using prepare statement method.

The problem is that The function return Nothing "null".

The function:

```
function login($username, $password)
{

    $username = sanitize($username);
    $password = md5($password);

    global $connect;

    $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ? ");

    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($id);
    $result = $stmt->fetch();

    $stmt->close();
    $connect->close();

    return $result;
}
```

The error I'm getting :

> "mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null
>   given in"

I don't know what's the problem!

---

Latest results:

```
function login($username, $password)
{
    global $connect;

    $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ? ");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
        $result[] = $row;
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $connect->close();

    return $result;
}
```

> Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in  " $result[] = $row;"

Comment: Can you add your db connection class as well?

Comment: Using `md5` for password hashes is just as insecure as not hashing them at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost every thing is ok, except you can not get the results from fetch statement as you do.

All depends on how your login function will work, you can do it in many ways, I will demonstrate 3 examples and leave it up to you:

**For both solutions:** 
In your sql statement, you could select specific fields you want or all fields:

```
SELECT `user_id`, `email`, `username`, `password` FROM `users`......etc...
```

Or all fields like:

```
SELECT * FROM `users`......etc...
```

**Solution 1:** 
Replace

```
$stmt->bind_result($id);
$result = $stmt->fetch();
```

With this

```
$output = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $output->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    $result = $row;
}
```

And call your login method/function, I injected a test user for test:

```
print_r(login("user", "1234"));
```

The results I get from my dummy test database, an array with all fields data from database table regarding the specific user as follows (I have used star * in my `SELECT` statement):

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => user@user.com [2] => user [3] => 1234 )
```

**Solution 2:** 
We keep the 2 lines we removed earlier, but add variables that will contain the value fetched from the database, it should be in the same order as in the `SELECT` statement, if you chose star (*) then you need to write all fields in database order. Our `bind_result` statement will deliver us the results from database, if you miss one field it won't work and return error.

Replace

```
$stmt->bind_result($id);
$result = $stmt->fetch();
```

With this

```
$stmt->bind_result($db_user_id, $db_email, $db_username, $db_password);
$stmt->fetch();
```

If you need user email address, then use `$db_email` variable, you can put all or partial results in array and return it or even return single value, it is up to you.

**Solution 3**

This solution combination of 1 and 2.

Replace

```
$stmt->bind_result($id);
$result = $stmt->fetch();
```

With this

```
$stmt->bind_result($db_user_id, $db_email, $db_username, $db_password);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $db_user_id;
}
```

The same here, if you need user email address, then use the `$db_email` variable, you can put all or partial results in array and return it or even return a single value. It is up to you.

---

**Note:** 
To reduce the chance of test failure, while I was testing I have disabled `sanitize($username)` and `md5($password)`. So I worked only with plain text, just to test and see if everything works as expected. When the job is done you can activate them again. 
I advise you also to use an alternative hashing solution, as md5 is deemed non-secure for passwords. See the PHP manual page for [Best Practices](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.bestpractice).

Comment: Thank you very much, everything same to be better, but I got this error after I did as you said. The error occurs in  $result[] = $row;

Comment: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in

Comment: which solution are you working with? I have edited my answer, pls check it again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. The third one worked like a charm.  I just removed "mysqli_num_rows"  and replaced it with  !empty();    Thank you again .

Comment: No problem, you are indeed welcome and good luck. It all depends again what is the requirement, adding 3 example give opportunity to find the best solution.